# How to access the array being passed by .reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a JavaScript object:

```js
const movies = [
  {'title' : 'Inception', 'rating' : 8.8},
  {'title' : 'Interstellar', 'rating' : 8.6},
  {'title' : 'The Dark Knight', 'rating' : 9.0},
  {'title' : 'Batman Begins', 'rating' : 8.3}
]
```

For example I wanted to do is to calculate the average rating using `.reduce()` so I'm stuck here:

```js
const averageRating = movies.filter(movie => movie['rating'] > 8.5).reduce((acc, movie) => (acc+movie['rating'])/2,  /* The rating of the first value of this array*/)
```

How can I access the array being processed by `reduce()` to get the rating first movie (TO USE IT'S FIRST ELEMENT.rating AS THE INITIIAL VALUE)? I know the first value assigned to `acc` by default is the first but it is an object in this case.

I know there are better ways to solve this particular situation, I have actually solved it, but I don't know if I can reach the same result this way?

```js
const movies = [{
    'title': 'Inception',
    'rating': 8.8
  },
  {
    'title': 'Interstellar',
    'rating': 8.6
  },
  {
    'title': 'The Dark Knight',
    'rating': 9.0
  },
  {
    'title': 'Batman Begins',
    'rating': 8.3
  }
]
const averageRating = movies.filter(movie => movie['rating'] > 8.5).reduce((acc, movie) => (acc + movie['rating']) / 2,)

console.log(averageRating)
```

Comment: reduce passes accumulator and current value, it did not pass original array. What result you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the initialValue of acc to be the rating of the first element being processed by reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you note the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the `reduce` function, it accepts four parameters.

1. accumulator
2. currentValue
3. currentIndex
4. array

So in your case, you can do the following:

```js
const averageRating = movies
                       .filter(movie => movie['rating'] > 8.5)
                       .reduce((acc, movie, idx, arr) => (acc+movie['rating'])/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the array the was passed to it.

Set the accumulator's initial value to be `0` - that would prevent reduce from throwing an error when the array is empty. Divide each number by the length of the filtered array, and add the result to the accumulator to get the average.

```js
const movies = [{"title":"Inception","imdbRating":8.8},{"title":"Interstellar","imdbRating":8.6},{"title":"The Dark Knight","imdbRating":9},{"title":"Batman Begins","imdbRating":8.3}]

const averageRating = movies
  .filter(movie => movie.imdbRating > 8.5)
  .reduce((acc, movie, i, arr) => acc + movie.imdbRating / arr.length, 0)
  
console.log(averageRating)
```

Comment: It works when you divide just the current item's rating, and not sum like you did. Just run the snippet.

Comment: The math is simple (x + y + z) / 3 = x / 3 + y / 3 + z / 3.

Comment: is there a way to set the accumulator's initial value to the rating of the second element for example ?

Comment: Why? What happens if the filtered array has only single element or non at all? Setting this to 0 would ensure that it works no matter how many items there are.

Answer (score 1):

the full `.reduce` signature is:

```js
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

based on that, you can write:

```js
const averageRating = movies
  .filter((movie) => movie["rating"] > 8.5)
  .reduce((acc, movie, index, array) => (acc + movie["rating"]) / array.length, 0);
```

and have access to the `array` inside the reduce function

Answer (score 1):

Consulting the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can see that the callback of `reduce` has the following signature

```
function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array)
```

Thus

```
array
  .filter(x => ...)
  .reduce((ac, cv, i, ar) => {
    //here ar is the array you are calling reduce, ie the array resulting from filter
  })
```

Comment: I wanted to use that array in the initialValue argument , not inside the callback function

Answer (score 1):

Ah okay, try this

```js
const movies = [
  {'title' : 'Inception', 'rating' : 8.8},
  {'title' : 'Interstellar', 'rating' : 8.6},
  {'title' : 'The Dark Knight', 'rating' : 9.0},
  {'title' : 'Batman Begins', 'rating' : 8.3}
]

// On each reduce iteration you modifying object property,
// not array value. To calculate average, you adding acc.rating
// to current movie.rating and when current iteration equals
// array length (last iteration) you divide accumulated value
// by array length (number of entries that was accumulated).
const averageRating = movies.filter(movie => movie['rating'] > 8.5)
.reduce((acc, movie, i, a) => ({
  'rating': (acc.rating + movie.rating)/(i+1==a.length?a.length:1)
}));

console.log(averageRating);
```

Comment: that worked !, but I couldn't really understand how this code worked

Comment: Well, what part? about accumulating object properties or about calculating average value?

Comment: accumulating object properties,

Comment: basically on each reduce iteration you modifying object property, because you accumulating not array values, but objects in array, so you use `({ 'rating': acc.rating + movie.rating })`. But you want not only accumulate them, but also calculate average, so you wrap it like: `({ 'rating': (acc.rating + movie.rating)/(i+1==a.length?a.length:1) })` - adding `acc.rating` to current `movie.rating` and when current iteration equals array length (last iteration) you divide accumulated value by array length (number of entries that was accumulated).